# Which Jersey dependency should I use?

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, tomcat, jersey

I am trying to set up Jersey with JAX-RS for my RESTful web application but I am overwhelmed by the amount of options.

I'm currently working in Eclipse and deploying to an Apache Tomcat 7 server. I'm using Maven to manage the project dependencies. I am also very new at this.

The Jersey options are very vague in their descriptions and I'm wondering if someone who has been here before can advise me on which dependency/package I need.

Jersey-Maven Page: https://jersey.java.net/documentation/latest/modules-and-dependencies.html

Answer (score 0):

If you do not have a good reason to use Tomcat, I suggest that you use a **fully compliant Java EE container** such as [Wildfly](http://wildfly.org/) instead. That way you will have all the **Java EE API:s** available out of the box, and you will not have to worry about downloading the right version of libraries and so on.

Comment: Thanks for the tip, I hadn't heard of it. In this case though, I have to Tomcat

Comment: Check this page out, it is about using Jersey in Tomcat: http://javahash.com/jersey-hello-world-example/